# Spring: need to instanciate singletion twice, in different context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, components

My Springboot application has a module providing a technical feature

Inside this module (let's call it MyModule), all `@Component` classes are singleton: they need to be instantiated only once

```java
package my.module;

interface IMyFeature {
}


@Component
class MyFeature implement IMyFeature {  // is a singleton

    private final MyOtherClass1 myOtherClass1;
    private final MyOtherClass2 myOtherClass2;

    @Autowired
    public MyFeature(MyOtherClass1 myOtherClass1,    // a singleton is injected
                     MyOtherClass2 myOtherClass2) {  // a singleton is injected
        this.myOtherClass1 = myOtherClass1;
        this.myOtherClass2 = myOtherClass2;
    }

}


@Component
class MyOtherClass1 {  // is a singleton

    private final MyOtherClass2 myOtherClass2;

    @Autowired
    public MyOtherClass1(MyOtherClass2 myOtherClass2) { // a singleton is injected (same instance as the one injected to MyFeature)
        this.myOtherClass2 = myOtherClass2;
    }

}


@Component
class MyOtherClass2 {  // is a singleton

    @Autowired
    public MyOtherClass2() {
    }

}
```

Outside this module (i.e. other modules of my application), it is possible to inject classes from the module MyModule when this service is needed

```java
package other.module1;

class FooBar {

   private final IMyFeature myFeature;     

   @Autowired
   public FooBar(IMyFeature myFeature) {
       this.myFeature = myFeature;
   }

}


package other.module2;

class HelloWorld {
     
   private final IMyFeature myFeature;     


   @Autowired
   public FooBar(IMyFeature myFeature) { // here I want myFeature to be the same instance than the one obtained by constructor of other.module1.FooBar
       this.myFeature = myFeature;
   }

}
```

This is working nice.

Now, I would need a new module (let's call it StrangeModule) that needs to run the feature of MyModule **in a different configuration context**. To do so, it needs to get its own instance of all singleton `@Component` defined in MyModule

```java
package strange.module;

class StangeClass {

   private final IMyFeature myFeature;     

   @Autowired
   public FooBar(my.module.IMyFeature myFeature) {
    // !!! here I DO NOT WANT myFeature to be the same instance than the one obtained by other.module1.FooBar and other.module2.HelloWorld
    // !!! I also DO NOT WANT that MyOtherClass1 and MyOtherClass2 instances to be the same as the ones obtained for other.module1.FooBar and other.module2.HelloWorld
       this.myFeature = myFeature;
   }

}
```

Any idea about what should I do to reach what I want to do?

Comment: If you need two instances, it's by definition not a singleton. So don't use that scope, and instead use a scope like `@Named`.

Comment: This isn't a singleton anymore, but a multiton. There is the notion of [`@Qualifier` in spring(`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) that allows to instantiate multiple beans of same types. The whole thing, however, smells like an [XY problem (`meta.stackexchange.com`)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need that second context, and is there a way to achieve this in another way?

Comment: Before posting this question, I already considered the `@Qualifier` possibility (as far as I understand it is the same as `@Named`)

However, I did not find a nice way to do it (maybe I missed something...). According to my modest knowledge of `@Qualifier`, I would need - for each class of `my.module` - to remove `@Component` and to create two inheriting classes, having `@Component` and `@Qualifier("the.qualifier.name")`

Comment: You might probably want to create multiple application context configurations. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-hierarchy I have not tried this myself, but worth a try